# Will the Cursed Sword's one-hit death effect apply if it's in my backpack?

Tags: dead-cells

The description of the Cursed Sword says "One hit and you're dead", presumably meaning you will die in one hit while it is equipped. However, there's a mutation called Porcupack that lets you hit enemies with the melee weapon in your backpack.

Will I die from a single hit if I have a Cursed Sword in my backpack?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you will die in a single hit if you have a Cursed Sword in your backpack. This occurs regardless of whether you have the Porcupack mutation.

Source: I died after thinking I'd found a clever way around the curse. I verified my results in the training room.